# Link menu item to an element ID on the same page

Tags: 6, routes

I want to link my menu items not to a page, but to a specific ID of a div tag on the same page, so if anyone click on it would go to the div section. basically its because I want to make a list of some items in my page.

I appreciate any guidance, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well I just figured that out, I can simply link it like: node/515#node-2 so it wont refresh the page and goes straight to the div.

node/515 (same page that my menu are in), but the thing is it doesnt work with url alias so better stick to the classic node url's